# Is it a good practise in Android to update a flow from an activity class and consume it in non-activity class?

Tags: android, kotlin, textureview

I have a [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView) which displays a live video from a third-party SDK. I am fetching the bitmap from the TextureView using the [getBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView#getBitmap(int,%20int)) method at regular intervals. I want to pass this Bitmap to a Mediator class which forwards it to multiple different classes, say Operation1.kt, Operation2.kt that have their own functionalities and apply their own set of operations to this Bitmap.

Hence, I was thinking of defining a flow in my Mediator class and my activity class would use and update it to emit the Bitmap. This flow would be collected in the same Mediator class and then pass it ahead to the other classes who need this Bitmap.

I know I can pass the object of the TextureView to my Mediator class and then fetch Bitmaps in the Mediator Class itself or make my TextureView static, but I am aware that both these approaches are bad as they might cause memory leaks.

The other approach I can go with is using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), but I want to use it as a last option.

So, is it a good practice to emit a flow from an activity class and collect it in a non-activity class? Are there any disadvantages/side-effects of doing so? I am curious to know this because I have not come across any example/tutorial which has done this.

Comment: Only if the classes that hold a reference to and consume the flow have a shorter lifespan than the activity. Keep in mind that usually, the lifespan of an activity is ended and restarted by a screen rotation, or the activity being placed in the background temporarily. In these cases, if some other class with a longer lifespan was still holding the reference, it would cause the first activity instance to be leaked.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Even if my activity which updates/emits the flow has a shorter life span, the flow is declared and consumed by the Mediator class. So, how will it cause the activity instance to leak? Because my Mediator class is not holding any reference to my activity. The activity is referring to the Flow defined in the Mediator class.

Comment: I missed that detail, since I've rarely seen a Flow declared/owned in one place and updated from another. So, you're right, that won't cause a leak, but it does seem to break the Single Responsibility Principle of object oriented programming. Whether that's acceptable in this specific case is hard to say without fully understanding the whole system, but even then it would be a matter of opinion. In general, if you're following widely accepted OOP principles, you will almost never expose a mutable class reference publicly from any class.

Comment: Main exception to that, in my opinion, is when this is in a performance-critical module of code where the object is mutated very frequently. Then for optimization reasons, it may not be practical to expose immutable classes that have to be replaced to make changes. Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't have structs.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. I think I should be not doing this.